# WPF Click-Once deployment promoting from stage to production

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I've a WPF Application that actually uses a Web server for downloading the app and execute it on the client... I've also created a staging enviorment for that application when I put the release as soon as new features are added / bug fixed.

I've not found a reasonable way of promoting from staging to production since the app.config is hashed... so I can't change my pointments (DB/Services) editing it...

My actual way is publishing for staging, increasing of 1 the publish version and publishing for production...but this is quite frustrating.... since I've to do twice the work...any sugeestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Our team encountered the same situation a year ago. We've solved the situation by following this steps:

- Determine the latest ClickOnce application version;
- Removing the *.deploy extensions;
- Making the necessary *.config file changes;
- Updating the manifest file (*.manifest) by using 'Mage.exe' and your certificate (see also: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx));
- Update the deployment manifest (*.application) in the application version directory and in the root directory, again by using 'Mage.exe';
- Adding back the *.deploy extensions.

Hereby a short code sample for calling Mage, really not that complicated though.

```
// Compose the arguments to start the Mage tool.
string arguments = string.Format(
@"-update ""{0}"" -appmanifest ""{1}"" -certfile ""{2}""",
deploymentManifestFile.FullName,
applicationManifestFile.FullName,
_certificateFile);

// Add password to the list of arguments if necessary.
arguments += !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_certificateFilePassword) ? string.Format(" -pwd {0}", _certificateFilePassword) : null;

// Start the Mage process and wait it out.
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_mageToolPath, arguments);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process mageProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
mageProcess.WaitForExit();

// Show all output of the Mage tool to the current console.
string output = mageProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

// Determine the update of the manifest was a success.
bool isSuccesfullyConfigured = output.ToLower().Contains("successfully signed");
```

Comment: Yes we succeeded, I'll lookup a code sample of our implementation.

Comment: I'm tring to use mage but I've a question...how do you handle version? consider a sample of 1.1.0.0 in prod and 1.2.0.0 in staging... I want to promote 1.2.0.0 to prod, if the user has just downloaded the 1.2.0.0 from staging it will continue serving the old one (the one of staging with staging's settings)... do you also change the version number of do you use different signing certificates?

Comment: exceuse me Herman, how do you manage the same version on two different enviorment? for example 1.2 in test and in prod...do each version points to the right db?

Comment: Actually, we run this script separately on each environment. That way, we are able to alter the configuration file on each environment separately too. Does this help you?

Comment: Not so much Herman, ok for using mage...I was able to resign the file...but this doesn't help me much.... the problem is if I "promote" staging version (ex. 1.2) to prod (before it was 1.1) and I try to run from production I'll have that if the user has just tested the staging one it won't download the production one...

Comment: Ah I see, that's a separate problem I think! Are you talking about the ClickOnce message 'Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed'? If so, this can easily be solved by running this script (Start > Run) on the users computer: 'rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache'. We've encountered the same problem for users, who test the application. As far as we know, this is the only solution to the problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that response.... this means the final user can't have the 2 enviorment opened at the same time for cross checking data....

Comment: Unfortunately true... unless the user has multiple computers.